# How to clean cache on iOS 9 and iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, caching

I want to clean cache on all kinds of version's iOS,however,**it only work on iOS 7 and iOS 8**. On iOS 9 and iOS 10,the same code didn't work,this make me very confused.

In order to find the reason,I create a new demo with the same clean cache method and run on iOS 10,everything goes well,and cleaned cache successfully.So I think,the code I use to clean cache is no problem. **But why it didn't work on my own project when run on iOS 9 and iOS 10?**

For the sake of confirming whether the code has been calling when run on iOS 9 and iOS 10,I add a breakpoint in this method,it stopped at there.Method had been called,but didn't clean cache. **The method code I use to clean cache is:**

```
-(void)removeCache
{
    //===============清除缓存==============
    NSString *cachePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsAtPath:cachePath];

    // NSLog(@"文件数 ：%lu",(unsigned long)[files count]);
    for (NSString *p in files)
    {
        NSError *error;
        NSString *path = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:p];
        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])
        {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];
        }
    }
}
```

I really need some help,this issue had confused me 3 day.

Comment: In the method removeItemAtPath are you getting any error ?

Comment: 1) Use the debugger and verify that `removeItemAtPath` is actually being called. 2) Check the return value of `removeItemAtPath`. If it returns `NO`, log `error`.

Comment: @Rajat Yeah,the error shows "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "未能移除“Snapshots”，因为您没有访问它的权限。" UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8F517FD7-5E9D-4BCE-9839-87F56044ABA9/Library/Caches/Snapshots, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Remove
), NSUnderlyingError=0x128987870 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that iOS 9 and iOS 10 store some files in the Caches folder that your app isn't allowed to delete.

You can use the `NSFileManager isDeletableFileAtPath:` method to check.

```
-(void)removeCache
{
    //===============清除缓存==============
    NSString *cachePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsAtPath:cachePath];

    // NSLog(@"文件数 ：%lu",(unsigned long)[files count]);
    for (NSString *p in files)
    {
        NSError *error;
        NSString *path = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:p];
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path] && [[NSFileManager defaultManager] isDeletableFileAtPath:path])
        {
            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Error trying to delete %@: %@", path, error);
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Can't delete %@", path);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It said I didn't have the access to remove.

Comment: That's what I said. iOS is creating some files that you are not allowed to remove. Don't worry about them. Just remove the files that you can.

Comment: But these caches in my app is more than 1G,I can't let it go.I just want to remove these images in my app,it can been done in iOS 7 and iOS 8,but it did't work on iOS 9 and iOS 10.

Comment: Update your question with a list of some of the files that can't be deleted. Keep in mind that the files are created by iOS for your app and you simply are not allowed to delete them. It is something added in iOS 9. The files don't get created in iOS 8 and earlier. So yes, you must let it go since there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: This is one of log messages:`Can't delete /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/0CDB0171-6B11-45D0-87E0-96E994E3243A/Library/Caches/kuaijiankang/EGOCache/EGOImageLoader-1785480096`      The `EGOCache` is an old open source library,I am not sure if there any error in it.

Comment: You might want to add code to check the permission of the file to see why it can't be deleted. Perhaps the file is read-only. If it's a folder, it can't be deleted if any of the files in the folder can't be deleted.

Comment: Finally,I use the `EGOCache`'s own method to clear cache,it works.